# With React Router : How to render a component multiple times with differents props each time in a Route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So far I have this working but how to render a second Line_json under the first one with different props like senseAction isnegatif in the same path economie ?

```
           <Router> <Route
                        path="/economie"
                        render={props => (
                            <Line_json
                              {...props}
                              senseAction={"ispositif"}
                            ></Line_json>
                          )
                        }
                      /></Router>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the render function is just like a regular render, so you can add two times your component

```
<Router>
  <Route
    path="/economie"
    render={props => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Line_json
          {...props}
          senseAction={"ispositif"}
        <Line_json
          {...props}
          senseAction={"isnegatif "}
        ></Line_json>
      </React.Fragment>
      )
    )}
  />
</Router>
```

Given you need always one root parent for your components, you must add a `<React.Fragment>`

Comment: I  was missing <React.Fragment>, works like a charm now thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You can render it in a Fragment:

```
render={props => (
  <>
    <Line_json
      {...props}
      senseAction="ispositif"
    />
    <Line_json
      {...props}
      senseAction="dsgdsg"
    />
  </>
))}
```

Or an array with unique keys:

```
render={props => ([
    <Line_json
      {...props}
      key="ispositif"
      senseAction="ispositif"
    />
    <Line_json
      {...props}
      key="dsgdsg"
      senseAction="dsgdsg"
    />
  </>
])}
```